# Find a finite partition of unity in the centralizer of a von Neumann algebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras

Let $M$ be a von Neumann algebra and $\varphi$ is a faithful normal state on $M$. Suppose that $M_{\varphi}$ is a type II$_1$ factor.

Suppose we have the following conclusion: if $p$, $q$ are any two nonzero projections in $M_{\varphi}$, we can find $v\in M$ such that $v^*v=p$, $vv^*=q$ and $v\varphi=\frac{\varphi(p)}{\varphi(q)}\varphi v$.

If $\lambda\geq 1$, choose $n\geq 1$ such that $\frac{1}{n}\leq\frac{1}{\lambda}$. Then we can find a partition of unity $q_1,\dotsc,q_n$ in $M_{\varphi}$ and some projections $p_1,\dotsc, p_n$ (not necessarily orthogonal) such that $\lambda^{-1}\varphi(p_k)=\varphi(q_k)$.

I wonder how to construct the above $p_k$ and $q_k$ ($k=1,\dotsc,n$)?

If $a$ is a self-adjoint element $a$ in $M_{\varphi}$, we can take $q_k=E_{B_k}(a)$ and $\bigcup _{k=1}^nB_{k}=\sigma(a)$, where $E_{B_k}(a)$ is the spectral projection of $a$. Then we have $q_1+\dotsb+ q_n=1$. How to find the projections $p_k$ ($k=1,\dotsc, n$) such that $\lambda^{-1}\varphi(p_k)=\varphi(q_k)$?

I want to use the fact that $M_{\varphi}$ is diffuse,  but we can find $e_k$ such that $\varphi(e_k)= 
\lambda^{-1}\varphi(q_k)$. How to find
$p_k$ ($k=1,\dotsc, n$) such that $\lambda^{-1}\varphi(p_k)=\varphi(q_k)$?

Comment: Ah, it is so pleasantly restful on the eyes to see II$_1$ `II$_1$` (or you could do $\text{II}_1$ `$\text{II}_1$` or II₁ `II₁`) in place of the barbarically kerned $II_1$ `$II_1$`!